# the number of components of every separable metric space is at most counatble

Tags: analysis

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. A subset $D$ of $X$ is said to be a *component* of $X$ if if $D$ is connected and there is no connected subset of $X$, which is a proper superset of $D$. I know that the number of components $\mathbb{C}$ is at most countable, which can be proved as follows:

We can show that the components of a metric space have to be disjoint, and every point in $X$ has to be in one or the other of the components. Now consider the set $S=\{a+bi:a,b~\text{are rational numbers}\}$. Then each of the component must contain at least one of these points (as rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$), hence the number of components is $\leq$ the cardinality of $S$, which is countable.

I think, that **the number of components of every separable metric space** (that is one having a countable dense set) **can be at most countable**. Am I right?

Comment: What about irrationals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of all irrational numbers, as a subspace of the real line, is a separable metric space; each singleton is a component, and there are uncountably many (in fact continuum many) of them. The Cantor set is a *compact* metric space, and it too has continuum many components.

Comment: so under what conditions does a set have countable number of components?

Comment: Components of a *locally connected* space are open sets. So a space which is locally connected and separable can have only a countable number of components.

Comment: thanks! your reputation score is very significant! :)

Comment: It was significant for a moment, then someone gave me an upvote. Now I have to go and downvote some answers, to get back to $1729$, which (as you must know) is the third Carmichael number.

Comment: Yeah...i was talking about 1729...in a different context though...its is the smallest number that can be expressed in two different ways as the sum of two cubes, $1729=10^3+3^3=12^3+1^3$